# Compare month in two custom date fields using datetime

Tags: php, datetime

our site does festival reviews, and for this we want to be able to select a start date (datum) and an end date (eind_datum) via date time picker custom fields. Ultimately we want a function that determines whether the start and end date have the some month, so we end up with something like this

'1-4 Juli 2020' (instead of '1 Juli - 4 Juli 2020).

When the month is different we want it to be displayed as follows
'30 Juni - 4 Juli 2020'.

I have tried several things but none seem to work, the month needs to be in Dutch, I tried setting the locale but that didn't help, and the following code below throws an error at this line
'$first = $startdateTime->format('F');'

Anybody out here who might help ?

```
 <?php  

$start_date = get_field('datum');
$end_date = get_field('eind_datum');
$startdatetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_date);
$enddatetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end_date);
$first = $startdateTime->format('F');
$second = $enddateTime->format('F');
    
 if (get_field('eind_datum') and get_field('datum') and ($first == $second )) {
  echo  $start_date->format ('j'); echo "-"; echo $end_date->format ('j F Y') ;
 }
 elseif (get_field('eind_datum') and get_field('datum') and ($first != $second )) {
  echo  $start_date->format('j F'); echo "-"; echo $end_date->format ('j F Y') ; 
 }
 else {
  echo the_field('datum') ;
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```php
$start_date = get_field('datum');
$end_date = get_field('eind_datum');
$startdatetime = new DateTimeImmutable($start_date);
$enddatetime = new DateTimeImmutable($end_date);
$first = $startdatetime->format('F');
$second = $enddatetime->format('F');
    
 if ($start_date and $end_date and ($first == $second )) {
  echo  $startdatetime->format ('j'); echo "-"; echo $enddatetime->format ('j F Y') ;
 }
 elseif ($end_date and $start_date and ($first != $second )) {
  echo  $startdatetime->format('j F'); echo "-"; echo $enddatetime->format ('j F Y') ; 
 }
 else {
  echo $start_date;
 }
```

The problem in you code is that the variables are sometime called incorrectly. For example: `$start_date` is not an object, and you cannot call the method `format` on it... or `$startdateTime` is not defined it is rather `$startdatetime`

Comment: Sadly this gives an error "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTimeImmutable::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (13 oktober 2020) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character on line 26". Line 26 in this case is the $startdatetime line. The custom field date is formatted as Y-m-d H:i:s.

Comment: According to the error message, the date received is '13 oktober 2020' and not 13-10-2020... can you please make sure? simply `die(var_dump($start_date))` before the first `new DateTimeImmutable`

Comment: You are correct. Date is stored in sql as Y-m-d H:i:s, but advanced custom field output is set to j F Y (hence the initial confusion). Makes sense then that it displays 13 oktober 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating 2 formats under certain conditions, you can also create the format '1 July - 4 July 2020' and then remove the month with preg_replace () if the months are the same.

```
$dateStr = '1 Juli - 4 Juli 2020';
$dateStr = preg_replace('~^(\d+) (\w+) - (\d+) (\2)~',"$1-$3 $2",$dateStr);
```

If the months are unequal, nothing is removed.

Comment: that would be an ideal solution. However the $datestr would be '1 Juli 2020 - 4 Juli 2020' which I tried to solve with this code, but failed. 
$dateSt = preg_replace('~^(\d+) (\w+) (\d+) - (\d+) (\2) (\3)~',"$1-$4 $2 $3",$dateSt);
Also, How would I format the $datestr if using the values of the two custom fields ?

Comment: Juli is German. The DateTime format method always returns the months in English as July. I assumed that you already have the string "'1 Juli - 4 Juli 2020". Date formatting in languages ​​other than English is a different issue.